# Cppcheck does not output warnings when there exists a line: auto lambda = [](){};

Tags: c++, cppcheck

Here is a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of `main.cpp`:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    float a;
    auto lambda = [](){};
    return 0;
}
```

Running `cppcheck --enable-all --std=c++11 *.cpp` outputs:

```
Checking main.cpp ...
```

Removing `auto lambda = [](){};` makes cppcheck output the following:

```
Checkin main.cpp
[main.cpp:3]: (style) Unused variable: a
```

as expected. Why does `auto lambda = [](){};` make Cppcheck go silent with respect to the unused variable message? This happens with Cppcheck 1.82.

Comment: Does it happen only when the second variable is of a closure type?

Comment: Is this not a question for the CppCheck developers? Not sure what we can do about it here.

Comment: @KillzoneKid: `lambda` is not assigned to anything.

Comment: @KillzoneKid: You said _"Because it is not unsused since it is assigned"_. However, it is _not_ assigned, and it _is_ unused.

Comment: @KillzoneKid: Right, and the OP is asking why they _don't_ get a warning about it!

Comment: Looks like a bug or shortcoming in cppcheck.  Even with `--inconclusive`, not even a peep.

Comment: Not all tools are created equal. They are prone to errors and bugs. Don't take their results for granted. Chances are your compiler does a much better job at assessing your code.

Comment: One problem here, that I see, is that free software projects have moved away from the community model, in recent past. If I had this kind of a question, maybe 5-10 years ago, this project would certainly have a mailing list, I'd shoot a question there, expecting it to be received by a group of interested users, who'll likely have something useful to reply. Now, I pull up cppcheck's site, and what do I see? A bug tracker, and an IRC channel. No wonder people are stumbling into stackoverflow.com, when they have a WTF.

Comment: My *guess* is that cppcheck doesn't really understand lambdas, and rather than give false positives on variables which are captured and used inside the lambda, it assumes that all variables are so used.  (This doesn't explain why the variable `lambda` isn't warned about though.)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: There appears to be an incongruity in your comment. First you complain that there's no longer any place to shoot a question to be received by a group of interested users, then you report that the project has a bug tracker and an IRC channel. Just because neither is an email mailing list doesn't mean the project has "moved away from the community model", or that a question about the project can only be answered on Stack Overflow. There is also, in fact, an active forum linked-to from the project page, and that would be the proper place for this post.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: I agree that this question could be posed to the developers. Especially if it's a bug. I'm not sure if this is a bug or if I'm misusing Cppcheck. Oftentimes stackoverflow is quick to point out misusage of tools so I figured I'd give my question a shot here. I've also noticed that cppcheck devs often answer here too..

Comment: @JoakimThorén Stackoverflow won't and can't be a replacement for proper channels to communicate with the devs

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - A "forum" is not a mailing list.  Looking through the history of some of my mailing lists: during their most active times they got ~1200 messages a month, or 40 a day. I would not expect any forum "community" project come anywhere close to that. The last message on cppcheck's forum was several days ago.  If anyone knows of this kind of "forum" getting these many messages per day, I'd be interesting to see what it's all about. But I doubt it. And there's a difference between "why asked here" and "can only be answered here". I said former, not the latter.

Comment: @Passer By: People on SO frequently ask questions about why some software works the way it does. I wholeheartedly agree with you that SO should not and can not replace proper communication channels with devs. I think my question can be answered by users of cppcheck.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: I am not convinced that we need a mailing list also. If I thought that we would get increased volume thanks to the mailing list I would add it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: So a project with a bug tracker, IRC channel and active forum only adheres to the "community model" if it also has a mailing list getting ~1200 messages a month. Got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello I am a Cppcheck developer.

There is a shortcoming in the checker. So this missing warning is not intentional.

I created this ticket:
http://trac.cppcheck.net/ticket/8433

For information, this is not a very hard issue to fix.